# How to set a CSS hover to a SVG map

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I'm using this example:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3306362/

How do I add a hover to the counties?  I've tried:

```
.counties:hover {
    fill:red;
}

path d:hover {
    fill:red;
}
```

and some several others.  no luck.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. `counties` is the class of the `<g>` element, not the paths. So, first set a class (like `county`) for each path;
2. This is your main problem here: there is a `style()` for those paths in the D3 code, which is therefore a *subsequent* rule. So, if you want your CSS rule to override that subsequent rule, use `!important`:

   ```
   .county:hover {
       fill: red !important;
   }
   ```

Or, alternatively, change that `style()` in the code for an `attr()`.

Don't use `path:hover`, since there are paths for the states as well. Also, there is no `d` element (`path d:hover` in your question) neither in HTML nor in SVG. `d` is a path's attribute.

Here is the updated bl.ocks with those two changes: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9ebef1b8e2a11bd170c50bb4a3440628/8923484fd3715aa474f1eb31184d11da863e24dc